# Recovering lost VHDX / VM (deleted by Veeam)

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, data-recovery, disaster-recovery, veeam

Earlier this week a VM on one of our hypervisors experienced extended downtime (~24 hours) due to some Windows updates going wrong. I ultimately was able to fix the issue, and noticed yesterday that Veeam wasn't backing up the VM anymore as part of its backup/replication of that hypervisor.

I found that Veeam was running an "instant VM recovery" on the VM ever since it originally went down (on the 25th). The VM had been up and running a few days at this point so I cancelled the recovery because I was afraid it might overwrite the VM with old data. A soon as I canceled it Veeam deleted the VM...

Both VM and VHDX are gone off the hypervisor. The last good backup is from Monday night and it's a mission critical VM. I've resorted to trying to recover with data recovery software (EaseUS) but I'm not having any luck. It finds a VHDX dated from the 25th (when the server originally went down) and an AVHDX dated from around when the VM was deleted yesterday, but the VHDX isn't bootable (when I try mounting it it just shows unallocated space) and the size of the AVHDX it recovers doesn't match up with the size EaseUS displays prior to recovery (~4GB vs ~88GB). I tried reconnecting the two manually in Hyper-V but it just errors out.

I'm feeling pretty screwed here. I don't understand why Veeam even went into Instant VM recovery for the VM, or why it would delete the running VM after canceling. I'd contact Veeam support but my service contract expired and it happened on an unsupported version of Veeam.

Is there hope at all to recover the data? Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that blocks, where VHDX and AVHDX were located, are now rewritten and tools such as EaseUS cannot properly restore VHDX and AVHDX.

In the case AVHDX is smaller than the previous one, this means that some of the snapshots were merged. So, to boot the VM with a snapshot you have to specify AVHDX as the boot file, not VHDX.